# How can I find a cyclic path in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path

Is there any algorithm or approach to find a cyclic path within a graph, optimizing some cost function, e. g. maximizing a reward associated with edges. The optimal cyclic path would then be the one collecting most reward

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=W18FDEA1jRQ  gives you a condition to tell if you can traverse the whole graph ( edgewise).

Comment: Wouldn't doing a simple BFS work? Remember which vertices you've been to.